# Sorting an Array using .sort in an function equals Undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to create a new array that is copy of mine array and at the same time sort it using the value stored in numTeeth. I'm using the function sort to accomplish this task. The problem is that if I try to debug it using a console log it show as result the undefined value.

```
const speciesArray = [ 
  {speciesName:'shark', numTeeth:50}, 
  {speciesName:'dog', numTeeth:42}, 
  {speciesName:'alligator', numTeeth:80}, 
  {speciesName:'human', numTeeth:32}
  ];

const sortSpeciesByTeeth = arrayIn => {
  arrayIn.sort( function (a, b) {
    return a.numTeeth - b.numTeeth;
  });
}

console.log(sortSpeciesByTeeth(speciesArray))
```

While if I use the same code without declaring it as separate function it works despite it sort the original array. What I don't want in the final code. Example

```
const speciesArray = [ 
  {speciesName:'shark', numTeeth:50}, 
  {speciesName:'dog', numTeeth:42}, 
  {speciesName:'alligator', numTeeth:80}, 
  {speciesName:'human', numTeeth:32}
  ];

speciesArray.sort( function (a, b) {
  return a.numTeeth - b.numTeeth;
});

console.log(speciesArray)
```

Comment: You need to return the result array from `sortSpeciesByTeeth ` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You have to `return` something from the function  `sortSpeciesByTeeth`, by default `undefind` is returned.

**2)** If you want a copy of original array then you can use spread syntax

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array. - MDN

```
const sortSpeciesByTeeth = (arrayIn) => {
  return [...arrayIn.sort((a, b) => a.numTeeth - b.numTeeth)];
};
```

or

```
const sortSpeciesByTeeth = (arrayIn) => [
  ...arrayIn.sort(({ numTeeth: nT1 }, { numTeeth: nT2 }) => nT1 - nT2),
];
```

```js
const speciesArray = [
  { speciesName: "shark", numTeeth: 50 },
  { speciesName: "dog", numTeeth: 42 },
  { speciesName: "alligator", numTeeth: 80 },
  { speciesName: "human", numTeeth: 32 },
];

const sortSpeciesByTeeth = (arrayIn) => {
  return [
    ...arrayIn.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.numTeeth - b.numTeeth;
    }),
  ];
};

console.log(sortSpeciesByTeeth(speciesArray));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a JS arrow function, the first statement is only implicitly returned if your function body is not wrapped in braces. This means `sortSpeciesByTeeth` is not returning anything. You need to just add a `return` statement:

```js
const speciesArray = [ 
  {speciesName:'shark', numTeeth:50}, 
  {speciesName:'dog', numTeeth:42}, 
  {speciesName:'alligator', numTeeth:80}, 
  {speciesName:'human', numTeeth:32}
  ];

const sortSpeciesByTeeth = arrayIn => {
  return arrayIn.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.numTeeth - b.numTeeth;
  });
}

console.log(sortSpeciesByTeeth(speciesArray))
```

Your original sortSpeciesByTeeth function *was* actually sorting the list, but it was just falling off the end without returning anything, therefore implicitly returning `undefined` to the `console.log` statement. (So if you sorted the array before logging it you would also have gotten the desired result):

```js
const speciesArray = [ 
  {speciesName:'shark', numTeeth:50}, 
  {speciesName:'dog', numTeeth:42}, 
  {speciesName:'alligator', numTeeth:80}, 
  {speciesName:'human', numTeeth:32}
  ];

const sortSpeciesByTeeth = arrayIn => {
  arrayIn.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.numTeeth - b.numTeeth;
  });
}

sortSpeciesByTeeth(speciesArray)
console.log(speciesArray)
```